# Returning dynamic data in popup windows for each row

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm having problems trying to return dynamic data into popup windows. For example if you were to refer to the sample link below, clicking the info button beside 'Williamson' returns 'Where is St. Andrews?' (the previous TerritoryDescription).

Here's a sample that replicates the issue:
http://jsbin.com/iJunOsa/109/

This is the showDetails function that launches when the Info button is clicked:

```
$(function() {
 $("#grid").on("click", ".info-btn", function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var wnd = $("#details").data("kendoWindow");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr[data-uid]"));    

        var subItem = dataItem.Territories[0];
        console.log(subItem);    

        detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#view").html());
        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(subItem));
        wnd.center().open();    

        wnd.setOptions({
            title: "Territories"
        });
    });
});
```

This is the 'view' template called up in showDetails:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="view">
    <div id="details-container">
        <label><strong>Where is #= TerritoryDescription #?</strong></label>
        <p>#= TerritoryDescription # is in...</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Lastly, the following template has been used to display the buttons:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="territoriesTemplate">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="resultTable">
    #for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
      <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="hasTooltip">#:Territories[i].TerritoryDescription#</a>&nbsp;
            <button class="info-btn">Info</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    #}#
  </table>
</script>
```

Any idea how I can rectify this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Code you are selecting the index [0]

```
var subItem = dataItem.Territories[0]; // this will always return the first record of the Territories List . 

var index=$(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex; // Take the index where button 
var subItem = dataItem.Territories[index]; pass the index to the List.
```

Here is a example : http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka1/to5cn5mn/1/